# How do I make my input text wholly visible in PySimpleGUI

Tags: input, display, pysimplegui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imc3Y.png)

How do I get my program using PySimpleGUI to display the whole text information before the input box?

Suppose I have a long sg.Text('abcdefghijklmnopqrst')  - All of this text is not being displayed in the window.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `textwrap.wrap`

> Wraps the single paragraph in text (a string) so every line is at most width characters long. Returns a list of output lines, without final newlines.

Example code

```py
from textwrap import wrap
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def Frame(text, key, width=30):
    lines = wrap(text, width=width)
    height = len(lines)
    new_text = '\n'.join(lines)
    layout = [[sg.Text(new_text, size=(width, height)), sg.Input(key=key)]]
    return sg.Frame('', layout, pad=(0, 0))


Questions = [
    'How often do you use our products?',
    'Which features are most valuable to you?',
    'How would you compare our products to our competitors?',
    'What important features are we missing?',
    'What are you trying to solve by using our product?',
    'What other types of people could find our product useful?',
    'How easy is it to use our product?',
    'How would you rate the value for money?',
    'How likely are you to recommend this product to others?',
    'How could we improve our product to better meet your needs?',
]

font = ('Courier New', 10, 'bold')
sg.set_options(font=font)
sg.theme('DarkBlue3')

layout = [
    [Frame(question, f'Q {i}')] for i, question in enumerate(Questions)] + [
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Submit'), sg.Push()],
]
sg.Window('Product Survey Questions', layout).read(close=True)
```

[image]